# My hamburger menu lines are not aligned what to do

Tags: css, iphone, react-native, frontend, hamburger-menu

My hamburgers are not aligning on the screen

I have visited different style methods like alignItems but still no results. concerning margins positioning I cannot go further left separating each line (all 3 of them) by about 2 px each.
the main problem is the horizontal alignment of each line.

Can someone help, please?

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native" ;




export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <View style={menuIcon.mainLine}>

         <View style={menuIcon.line2}>
          <View style={menuIcon.line3}>
            </View>
             </View>
                 </View>
        ) 
    }
}

const menuIcon = StyleSheet.create({
   mainLine: {
        flex: 1,
backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
top  : 4,
height              : 6.5,
width               : 35,
  position            : 'absolute',
  marginTop              : 40,
  marginLeft             : 25,
 alignItems             : "stretch",
  left                : 0,
  right                : 0,
   borderRadius       : 20,
  borderStyle        : 'solid',
  borderWidth        : 1,
  borderColor        : 'rgba(205, 205, 205, 1)'
  },
    line2: {
        flex: 1,
backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
top  : 7,
height              : 6.5,
width               : 35,
  position            : 'absolute',
  marginTop              : 0,
  marginLeft             : 0,

  left                : 0,
  right                : 0,
   borderRadius       : 20,
  borderStyle        : 'solid',
  borderWidth        : 1,
  borderColor        : 'rgba(205, 205, 205, 1)'
  },
   line3: {
        flex: 1,
backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
top  : 7,
height              : 6.5,
width               : 35,
  position            : 'absolute',
  marginTop              : 0,
  marginLeft             : 0,

  left                : 0,
  right                : 0,
   borderRadius       : 20,
  borderStyle        : 'solid',
  borderWidth        : 1,
  borderColor        : 'rgba(205, 205, 205, 1)'
  }
  })

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend using [react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons) for that.

but if you want to implement it yourself do this changes in your render function

```
render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <View style={menuIcon.mainLine}></View>
      <View style={menuIcon.line2}></View>
      <View style={menuIcon.line3}></View>
    </View>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually we dont write hamburger code by our self .. or any other buttons icons.

We use icons or images inside view and apply onPress on view itself

with react-native we use react-native-vector-icons library. Installation basic usage guide here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Yes, I know that but in this case, I have designed icons, so I would like to know how to draw and position it directly after exporting my design CSS files

Comment: first wrap all three lines inside single view with width and height and flexDirection = cloumn.. then... inside that write your line1,2,3 and properly align them.

Comment: and what you are doing is ... building flex1 then inside flex1 .. building flex2 .. then inside flex2 ..building flex 3

Comment: so create a container with .. height and width ... then inside container, you can draw all three lines ... and utilize available space with flex1 .. with some height